# PostgreSQL TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am executing a query in psycopg2 linked up to a PostgreSQL database. Here is the code in question:

```
with open('dataFile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    newLines = [line[:-1] for line in lines]
    curr=conn.cursor()
    lineString = ','.join(newLines)
    curr.execute("SELECT fields.fieldkey FROM fields LEFT JOIN zone ON zone.fieldkey=fields.fieldkey WHERE zone.zonekey = %s;", (newLines[0]))
    rows = curr.fetchall()
```

There's no issue connecting to the DB, and the type of lines[0] is definitely string, I checked that. Is there something wrong in the syntax of my string formatting?

The error I get, to clarify is this:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There must be a comma after `lines[0]` to make that a tuple.

```
curr.execute("""
    SELECT fields.fieldkey
    FROM fields
    LEFT JOIN zone ON zone.fieldkey=fields.fieldkey
    WHERE zone.zonekey = %s;
""", (lines[0],))
```

Since the [`execute` method is expecting a sequence (or a mapping)](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) it iterates over the string you provided surrounded by parenthesis. So it is necessary to explicitly make that a tuple. The same result, with clearer code, can be had using the [`tuple` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple):

```
(tuple(lines[0]))
```